# In Lua, How do I call a variable using index?

Tags: indexing, lua

```
local index = 1
```

> Defining Function

```
local function PickGlass()
    local RandomNum = math.random(0,1)
    local Platform1 = game.Workspace.Tester.Platform(index)
    local Platform2 = game.Workspace.Tester.Platform(index + 1)

    local function Falling()
        Platform1.Anchored = false 
    end
    local function OtherFalling()
        Platform2.Anchored = false
    end
    if RandomNum == 1 then
        Platform1.Touched:Connect(Falling)
    end
    if RandomNum == 0 then 
        Platform2.Touched:Connect(OtherFalling)
    end
    index = index + 1
end
```

> Running Function

```
while index < 4 do
    PickGlass()
    index += 2


end
```

It wont let me use index when defining Platform 1 and 2. How do I use it?

Comment: We need more details - do you want to have two different variables called `index`? If that is the case, you can use local variables.

Comment: If this is Roblox code, then you're trying to call `Platform`, an Instance, which doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do on that line?

Comment: each time the function runs I want it to be the next Platform in the folder by using Index to have it go up each time and change which Platform the function effects

Comment: I tried using 2 index variable but that didnt work either, It gave me the error message that Platform wasnt a part of the workspace even when I put index at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to index an instance using a variable, you can do either:

```lua
game.Workspace.Tester.Platform[tostring(index)]
-- or
game.Workspace.Tester.Platform:FindFirstChild(tostring(index))
```

---

You can’t do:

```lua
game.Workspace.Tester.Platform(index)
```

Because that is indicating that you want to call the `Platform` method which doesn’t exist on Tester. (Plus you’d need `:` to pass `self` first on any function call)